Seeking Recommendations for Historical Resources on the Dirichlet Problem in PDEs
I am currently working on my bachelor's thesis, which focuses on the Dirichlet problem in partial differential equations. As part of my research, I am keen to understand the historical development and background of this problem.
Could anyone kindly recommend comprehensive resources or books that delve into the history and evolution of the Dirichlet problem? Any pointers towards seminal papers or key historical texts would also be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Useful might be Måns Petter Alskog's 2023 Bachelor thesis The History of the Dirichlet Problem for Laplace's Equation at Linköping University (thesis itself is dated December 2022; Bachelor degree awarded in 2023).
